# How to get parameter from another datatable column?

Tags: javascript, datatable

My objective is to carry multiple parameters in same row but from different column. In my case, each row contain of 7 columns. but only 3 parameters that I need to pass to `btnApprove1` function. This function will appoint to other API which require all that 3 parameters.

So how to carry `service_id`, `project_id` and `staff_id` into `btnApprove` function when clicked?

```
columns: [
    { data : "service_id", "className": "text-center" },
    { data : "project_id", "className": "text-center" },
    { data : "staff_id", "className": "text-center" },
    { data : "status", "className": "text-center",
        render: function(data){
            if (data == "1001") {
                return  "<span onclick='btnApprove(&quot;"+data+"&quot;)'</span>";
            }
            else {
                return data;
            }
        }
    },
    { data : "lorry", "className": "text-center" },
    { data : "car", "className": "text-center" },
    { data : "van", "className": "text-center" }
]

function btnApprove(service_id, project_id, staff_id){

    console.log(service_id, project_id, staff_id)

    var params = {
        "service_id": service_id,
        "project_id": project_id,
        "staff_id": staff_id
    };

    params = JSON.stringify(params);

    $.ajax ({
        ...
    });

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your requirement, and what does `btnApprove` do exactly?

Comment: I just update my posting.

Comment: Can you also paste the definition of `btnApprove`? We need to see how it's defined, its parameters and what it does.

Comment: I just update the function, the function need to received 3 parameters from datatable above. this function is usual I do. but I do not how to get from datatables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve this issue by applying this.

```
{ data : "status", "className": "text-center",
    fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
        if (oData.status == "1001") {
            var stat = '<span class="badge badge-warning font-11">Approval</span><br/>';
            $(nTd).html("<span onclick='btnApprove(&quot;"+oData.service_id+"&quot;, &quot;"+oData.project_id+"&quot;, &quot;"+oData.staff_id+"&quot;)'>"+stat+"</span>");
        }
        else if (oData.status == "1000") {
            var stat2 = '<span class="badge badge-primary font-11">Registered</span>';
            $(nTd).html("<span onclick='btnNotApprove(&quot;"+oData.service_id+"&quot;, &quot;"+oData.project_id+"&quot;, &quot;"+oData.staff_id+"&quot;)'>"+stat2+"</span>");
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery Datatable [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) for the column cell `render()` function, it takes four parameters, the third parameter is called `row`, and it's an array of values each representing the value of the column with the respective index. You can use this parameter to pass the right values to your `btnApprove` function.

In the code block below, I make use of [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on the `row` array to only get the first three values you need. [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) also help make string HTML more readable.

```
render: function(data, type, [service_id, project_id, staff_id]) {
    if (data === '1001') {
        return `
            <span onclick="btnApprove('${service_id}', '${project_id}', '${staff_id}')">
                ${data}
            </span>
        `;
    }
    return data;
}
```

To make sure that your `<span>` click event has access to `btnApprove` when used as a string like you have, it needs to be declared globally, on thing you can do is to change the definition of the function from:

```
function btnApprove(service_id, project_id, staff_id) {
```

To:

```
btnApprove = function(service_id, project_id, staff_id) {
```

Comment: I try to apply but get this error at console. `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at render (<anonymous>:56:33)`

Comment: Were you getting this error before? Or was it right after you tried my answer?

Comment: I think I know what the issue is.

Comment: Hi, I just find the solution. btw thanks for your effort to help.